# Why TCP packets loss occurs when using Exanic X10 NIC to get frame data which the firmware version is 20210604?

Tags: tcp, fpga, tcpdump

I used one `Exanic X10 NIC` to get frame data and using `tcpdump` command to capture the same network interface simultaneously.In my program log, I printed every frame bytes data and the TCP sequence after calling `exanic_frame_frame` function, which located in the `Exanic X10` driver API. Finally, I found the one problem is that some TCP packets lossen by calling the `exanic_frame_frame` func to get frame data. But the TCP packets were not lossen in the `pcap` file by `tcpdump` command. So what does caused the problem? Does the firmware version 20210604 stable or some other reason caused this?

I have run my program and using `tcpdump` to capture packets so many times.But the TCP packets loss by calling `exanic_receive_frame` func (the `Exanic X10` driver API) always occurs. 788 TCP packets have lossen in my program compared with the `pcap` file by `tcpdump` command. I truly want to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.